# proving "e" irrational using convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

So my math professor in college gave us this problem:

$$U_n=\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}\frac{1}{k!}$$

$$V_n=U_n+ \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}$$

The problem has two questions:

1- Prove that the two series are adjacent (easy)

2- Let $e$ be their limit, prove that $e$ is irrational.

I have no idea how to start the second part, since I don't have a professor that does the problems the first professor gives us, so I have a lack in reasoning skills, I tried proof by contradiction, but no result.

also I'm new to the site so I don't know how to use the symbols so sorry for that.

Comment: What does it mean for series to be adjacent?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=+\infty$, what does it mean to discuss the rationality or irrationality of $+\infty$?!?

Comment: @avid19 i study in french so i don't know the english terminology, but basically they have diffrent variation, and lim(vn-un)=0

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I can't exactly follow on what you mean by that, i never came across the ir/rationality of +inf , and i'm falling short in resources because of the reasons i stated above.

Comment: I don't know what what it means to study the rationality of infinity. Neither does @JackD'Aurizio but that is what you are asking. So YOU must know what it means.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio , i'm terribly sorry, it's k! not k...i've been stuck in this problem for a while can't believe i've forgotten that.

Comment: See [Wikipedia's demonstration](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(nombre)#Irrationalit.C3.A9) (in French).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letter $e$ is used for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}1/k!$ where, by definition, $0!=1. $ So $e=1+\lim_{n\to \infty} U_n$. If $e$ were rational then $n!e$ is an integer for some $n>0.$ (For example if $e=a/b$ with $a,b\in Z^+$ let $n=b$.)$$\text { But......   } n!e=A_n+B_n ,$$ $$\text {where }  A_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}1/k!=\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}(n!/k!)\in Z$$ and $$0<B_n=n!\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}1/k!=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}n!/k!<\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^{-1}(n+2)^{-j}=(n+2)(n+1)^{-2}<1$$ so $B_n$ is not an integer.